# about the sence of variation of a composant function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Excuse me for the bad expression.
We know that the sence variation of the composant of an decreasing function with a nonincreasing function is a decreasing function.
But if f(x)={x^2} and g(x)=-2x+3 then we'll find the opposite  whene x>3/2. I want to know where is the problem??
thank you.

Comment: $x^2$ is not an increasing function and $-2x+3$ is not a non increasing function, it is strictly decreasing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_calculus_and_analysis

Comment: i mean whene x >3/2

Comment: $g(x)=-2x+3$ is NOT a non increasing function. Non increasing is not a synonimous of decreasing. This is why the composition theorem doesn't work in this case.

Comment: would you  tell me what is the difference between the two concepts please @Raffaele

Comment: A function is called monotonically increasing (also increasing or nondecreasing), if for all  x and y such that x ≤ y one has f (x) ≤ f (y).

Likewise, a function is called monotonically decreasing (also decreasing or nonincreasing) if, whenever x ≤ y, then f (x) ≥ f (y)    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_calculus_and_analysis